# BER for BPSK over AWGN Channel

Tags: bpsk

A BPSK scheme operating over an AWGN channel with noise power spectral density of \$N/2\$, uses equiprobable signals \$S_1(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{T} sin\ t}\$ and \$S_2(t) = -\sqrt{\frac{2E}{T}sin\ t}\$ over the symbol interval \$(0, T)\$.

If the local oscillator in a coherent receiver is ahead in phase by 45 degrees with respect to the received signal, the probability of error in the resulting system is (Answer key given is \$Q(\sqrt{\frac{E}{N}})\$**

Comment: Why don't you start by showing your reasoning about how a solution can be attained?

Comment: In fact, as you've already provided the answer, I'm not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

The AWGN channel with noise power spectral density 
$$\frac{N}{2}$$
And the signals:
$$s_1(t)=\sqrt{2\frac{E}{T}}\sin(t)\qquad t\in[0,T]$$
$$s_2(t)=-\sqrt{2\frac{E}{T}}\sin(t)=-s_1(t)$$

In a normal coherent oscillator, you would receive something like the following in the constellation diagram (noise not represented):

[image]

(the picture may be wrong because of the usage of sine or cosine, but you get the idea).

The red dashed line is the decision boundary, and the distance from the signal to this boundary represents the actual energy that the receiver can use to make the decision. So, in this case, it is obvious that the BER will be 
$$Q\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{2E}{N}}\bigg)$$

If the local oscillator in a coherent receiver is ahead in phase by 45°, it means that the receiver has is decision boundary rotated in the constellation diagram:

[image]

So the distance from the signal to the boundary is actually less than before, therefore the BER increases. How much? It depends on the distance to the boundary, so the new BER is:
$$Q\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{E}{N}}\bigg)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. very well explained.I have an exam coming up but I haven't taken up any formal classes for the course so finding the topic a bit difficult.Is BER and Probability of error calculation the same? Isnt the Pe given by Q(distance from the S to the boundary/ √(N/2)) in which case wdnt the Pe be Q((√2E)/√(N/2))=Q(2√(E/N)). And for For Pe calculations is this the standard method where I will have to find the constellation diagram with amplitudes of the signal represented in terms of E at the input of the receiver, then find the decision boundary, then the distance (Cont..)

Comment: from the decision boundary which will be in terms of the Energy content of the signal and then probability of error in terms of the Q function by normalizing it be dividing the distance in terms of E divided by √(N/2. Please correct me wherever I have gone wrong.

Comment: @Fawaz I'm kinda rusty on these topics, but there should be plenty of information on internet. Note that Pe and BER are different concepts: Pe is probability of error, normally understood in the symbol side. BER is the Bit Error Rate, and that always relates to the bits encoded in the transmitted symbols. In BPSK, as there's one bit in every symbol, note that Pe and BER should be the same. What you're saying seems right, let me verify it, keep it up!!

Comment: Thanks Sir. I have mainly ASK,FSK,PSK and BPSK in syllabus so I suppose since all of them have 1 bit/Symbol Pe and BER are the same. To get the final answer shouldn't we get signal to boundary distance as √(E/2). Also please confirm the method sir, ie I will always have to find the signal co-ordinates at the input of the receiver(ie after the local oscillator) in terms of E, then the decision boundary  and the pe in terms of the Q function. One more doubt is the value of the threshhold detector, wont it always be the distance of the signal from the decision from boundary?